# align a bottom constraint of one view to another view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

How to align a bottom constraint of one view to another view in SwiftUI?
For example:
I have an image and a text and I want to align text to bottom constraint of the image and give 10 padding. How can I do that?

For example:  I am using following code for ZStack. And the Text is aligned at centre of the image and padding is done at centre. But I want it to be aligned at bottom.

```
ZStack {
        let image = UIImage(named: "blockedEmpty")
        Image(uiImage: image!).resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        Text("Image text").offset(CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 10.0))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **overlay** here:

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let image = UIImage(named: "blockedEmpty")
        Image(uiImage: image!).resizable().frame(width: 300, height: 300).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay(Text("Image text").padding(), alignment: .bottom)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want the text to be over the image with the bottom same as the image. I could give the padding of the text such that it goes 10 px above the bottom of image. Basically I need to know, how can bottom of 2 elements be same?

Comment: @ShivaniBajaj: answer updated for your need